# srand(time(NULL)); what does this statement actually doing

Tags: c++

I just want to know how this srand function is working hear by passin time(NULL) as a parameter

```
int Secret; // variable declaration
srand(time(NULL)); //calling srand function
Secret = rand() % 10 + 1; //generation random no between 0 and 10
cout<<Secret;
```

Comment: It sets the seed. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: @Pete Becker fair enough. I'll retract that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time() gets the current time http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time

srand() seeds your the rand() psudo-random number generator.

This is the C style way of doing things. The C++ idiom would be to use the random header and its functions.

See the example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/generate_canonical/

Mike

Comment: Suggestion: *Don't* link to cplusplus.com - it's full of errors and generally less complete/lower quality than a reference site like (for example) cppreference.com .